# html <area> tag added in Angular does not show "hand" pointer in Edge and IE

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, microsoft-edge

I have html component in Angular 5 project, which dynamically adds some `<area>` tags using `*ngFor` directive, among with "real" `<area>` tags.

```html
<map id="lbar" name="lbar">
  <area *ngFor="let link of globals.links" id="{{link.id}}" alt="{{link.alt}}" shape="rect" coords="{{link.coords}}"
    routerLink="{{link.link}}" />
  <area alt="Forums" href="https://blahblahblah/forums" coords="69,341,141,357" target="_blank" />
</map>
```

In Chrome, Firefox and Opera everything works and **looks** ok.
In Edge and IE11 routerLink works and navigates, but mouse pointer does not change to "hand" while cursor hovers the `<area>` tag.

[image]

I have tried to set cursor explicitly via css, but it hasn't helped. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using  in css   cursor: pointer;   ? it works fine for me.

Comment: Of course. As I wrote:"I have tried to set cursor explicitly via css".

Comment: Can you add you css pls

Comment: Here you are:   area{
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use CSS below and check whether it works or not.

```css
area {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Or you can also try to make a test with code below.

```html
<map id ="map4" name="map4">
    <area  shape ="poly" coords="5, 0, 100, 10, 94, 66, 0, 50" 
           href="javascript:void(0);"
           onmouseover="document.getElementById('img_id').style.cursor='pointer';" 
           onmouseout="document.getElementById('img_id').style.cursor='';"> 
</map>
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that areas from *ngFor were missing "href" attribute and adding 
href="javascript:void(0);" did the trick, without any CSS. Shame on Edge developers.